# Calling static methods in Smarty, using variable as class name

Tags: php, static, smarty

I want to do something like this:

```
{$foo = 'SomeClassName'}
{$foo::someStaticMethod()}
```

When I compile my template, I get an error: `Fatal error: Uncaught --> Smarty: Invalid compiled template for ...`

After the file is compiled, when trying to display the template, I get this error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '::' (T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM), expecting ',' or ';' in ...`

When I inspect the compiled template, it contains this statements: `<?php echo $_smarty_tpl->tpl_vars['foo']->value::someStaticMethod();?>`, which obviously is not valid PHP syntax (at the moment).

From my understanding of the last example [here](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/advanced.features.static.classes.tpl), Smarty should support this.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug in Smarty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Smarty documentation it seems like it is only supported for assigning the return code of your static function. Have your tried it like

```
{assign var=foo value=SomeClassName::someStaticMethod()}
```

If that doesn't help i suggest you write your own plugin: http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/plugins.writing.tpl, http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/api.register.plugin.tpl

With something like

```
<?php
$smarty->registerPlugin("function","callStatic", "smarty_function_callStatic");

function smarty_function_callStatic(array $params, Smarty_Internal_Template $template)
{
  if (isset($params['callable']) && is_callable($params['callable'])
  {
    return call_user_func_array($params['callable'], $params);
  }
}
```

Which in smarty syntax is then used like:

```
{callStatic callable='SomeClassName::someStaticMethod()'}

{callStatic callable='SomeClassName::someStaticMethod()' param1='123' param2='123'}
```

**Edit:**

I also tested the exact same code you mentioned in your question and it is working fine for me with the latest version (from https://github.com/smarty-php/smarty). The output is "123".

My Code example is the following:

```
require '../libs/Smarty.class.php';

class DemoClass {
    public static function foobar()
    {
        return '123';
    }
}

$smarty = new Smarty;
$smarty->display('index.tpl');

/**
 * index.tpl
 *
 {$foo = 'DemoClass'}
 {$foo::foobar()}
 */
```

Comment: `{assign var=bar value=SomeClassName::someStaticMethod()}` works fine. The problem occurs when using a variable as class name. This is also the case when assigning the return value: `{assign var=foo value="SomeClassName"}{assign var=bar value=$foo::someStaticMethod()}` produces the same error. Making a plugin is a nice workaround. Thanks! But still, doesn't it seem to be a bug in Smarty or an error in it's documentation?

Comment: I was using an old version of Smarty. Updating to the newest version fixed the problem :)